# Sufficient Statistic for a finite family of Normal distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, sufficient-statistics

Suppose we have a finite family of normal distributions $P=\{N(0, 1), N(0, 2), N(1, 2), N(2, 2)\}$ and we want to find a sufficient statistic for this family. Intuitively it is clear that as the means and variances of these distributions are not same so $T(\textbf{X})=(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i, \sum_{i=1}^nX^2_i)$ is sufficient for this family but how to mathematically prove that neither $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, nor $\sum_{i=1}^nX^2_i$ is sufficient for this family and the $T(\textbf{X})$ mentioned above is sufficient for this family.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Sufficiency of $T$ follows from its sufficiency for $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, by the factorisation theorem. I'm not sure how to prove that there isn't a smaller sufficient statistic -- you have to consider eg mean^2+variance as well as mean alone or variance alone, and also statistics with just four values.